# How to consume POST method in API RestFul using Xamarin

Tags: json, rest, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

You want to consume an API for the login of my application, the method that consumes that API receives 4 parameters

1. URL BASE
2. KEY
3. USERNAME
4. PASSWORD

the main problem is that I am not receiving the correct answer (status 200 OK)

[image: debug]

My classes LoginResponse is structured in a good way, the parameters are passed through a simple form, but when I deserialize the object I am getting the next output

But when I use POSTMAN to pass the same parameters, this answers me back successfully.

[image: postman]

I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong, can it be concatenated incorrectly? I lack code?

```
 public async Task<LoginResponse> GetToken(
           string urlAPILogin,
           string KeyLogin,
           string Rut,
           string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAPILogin);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("login", new StringContent(string.Format("/?k=" + KeyLogin + "&rut=" + Rut + "&password=" + Password) ,
                    Encoding.UTF8));
                var resultJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(
                    resultJSON);
                return result;

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

My resource dictionary contains

```
  <x:String x:Key="URLAPI">http://159.89.47.120</x:String>     
 <x:String:Key="KEY">afruo60kp5DXF7weN**********ObGS0TyIksfEppLPeGjl9hQHoja1LIfWp8YCTiA0GrZWodD2rPOe5DX8G9Yp3b</x:String>
```

I have omitted all my Key for obvious reasons, any help for me ??

Comment: your POSTMAN sample is sending all the data on the querystring, not the body

Comment: How can I send the data in the chain? I thought I was doing it that way! @Jason

Comment: @BodegaPangal create a `HttpRequestMessage` with the query string as part of the URL and use `HttpClient.SendAsync`

Comment: you suggest sending the parameters by an HttpRequestMessage and not occupying the PostAsync instead of a SendAsync? Could you recommend an answer? @Nkosi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `HttpRequestMessage` with the query string as part of the constructed URL and use `HttpClient.SendAsync`

```
//...

var uri =  "login?k=" + KeyLogin + "&rut=" + Rut + "&password=" + Password;
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

//...
```

Now there better ways to safely construct the URL, but this was meant to be a quick simple example of how to send the request. You can easily search this site for other ways to construct the URL.

Comment: where do I concatenate my urlBase with the parameters? Following your answer I have to use the "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ()", do I have to deserialize the object? I'm not getting results ... @Nkosi

Comment: You already had the BaseAddress URL to the client in your example.